# What is the best resource to learn malware analysis?

Tags: malware, professional-education

I am looking for a resource that helps learn malware analysis. I know about the practical malware analysis book but i am looking for something other than a book. For example a Site or video tutorials.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Learn reverse engineering, assembly language x86 and x64 preferably. If you don't have the time and patience to start learning those then you don't have the time and patience required to analyze malware on the lowest level. Programming is your friend so is networking and the security aspect of it especially. Once you get your feet wet in those subjects then start analyzing old malware and by old I mean OLD, progress your way to modern malware and more advanced exploitation techniques, but don't start trying to analyze bleeding edge 0day malware because you'll end up being lost. For the best resources I would suggest getting a book, do a search for reverse engineering tutorials and assembly tutorials, start to follow them and eventually download a book for more advanced topics in those specific subjects.

Answer (score 5):

The Practical Malware Analysis book itself comes with hands on exercises for each chapter with solutions in the back of the book.  It's a great resource that you should probably invest in.

If you're not familiar with reverse engineering topics then I would suggest learning [x86 Assembly](http://chadaustin.me/2009/02/a-brief-introduction-to-modern-x86-assembly-language/), [Windows Programming](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496995.aspx), and [Windows Internals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/windows-internals) concepts.  Pick a debugger a learn it like the back of your hand:

- [Windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)
- [Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/)
- [Immunity Debugger](http://debugger.immunityinc.com/)

Pick up a [free version of IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml).  There are [various tutorials](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/index.shtml) on IDA's site.